# A finite difference method for a nonlinear system of PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences, finite-element-method

I've been trying to write an explicit FDM for this nonlinear system of PDEs:

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = f(u, v) + \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial {x}^2} -  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(u \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \right) $$

$$ \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = g(v) +\frac{\partial ^2 v}{\partial {x}^2} -  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(v \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right) $$

The linear terms are discretized in the standard manner. However, I am not quite sure how to handle the last terms in the equations. My approach is to first apply the product rule (so I get $-\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + u \frac{\partial ^2 v}{\partial {x}^2}\right)$) and then use forward differences for each of the first derivatives. Is this approach correct? Are there any better ways to handle the last terms? Thank you very much in advance for the answers.

EDIT: I tried discretizing the equations as mentioned above, but found out that the term $u \frac{\partial ^2 v}{\partial {x}^2}$ causes a blow-up. If I disregard $u$ (which is discretized as $u_{j}^{m}$) in this term, the whole scheme appears to work. I've also tried discretizing $u$ as $u^{m}_{j - 1}$, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Lagrange interpolants for $u$ and $v$ on $x = -h,0, h$ you can compute $(v u')'$ at the midpoint as
\begin{equation}
(vu')'(0) = (A u_{-1} + B u_{0} + C u_{1})/(4 h^2) + O(h^2)
\end{equation}
where $A := v_{-1} + 4 v_{0} - v_{1}$, $B = -8 v_0$, $C = -v_{-1} + 4 v_0 + v_{1}$, with $u_{k} := u(kh)$, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried that but the scheme seems to blow up. It works just fine without the derivative products, so the problem must be with those terms. Do you have any other suggestions how to improve accuracy when discretizing those last terms?

Comment: @AnonymousUser, I have to admit I'm guessing at that stability criterion in my comment, I haven't worked out what it really is for the coupled system.

Comment: My time step is really small compared to the space step. My code might be wrong, so I'll check that. Anyway, thank you for the advice.

Comment: I removed my comments on the stability criteria because of a misreading on my part; it doesn’t affect the discretization though.

Comment: A back of the envelope calculation suggests an explicit time-stepping scheme for this system, as it stands, is probably always unstable.

Comment: A little late to the party, but expanding the derivates via chain rule for finite difference methods is an incorrect approach, it does not conserve mass. You should apply the FDM directly to the nonlinear derivative.